# Arrays in Magento Registry

Tags: magento-1.7

I am storing an array of values in registry.It works fine.But I am unable to retrieve the array values from the registry. For example,

```
$products=array(
            'product1'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('product1'),
            'product2'=>$this->getRequest()->getParam('product2'));

// saving in registry
Mage::register('orderproducts_products', array_filter($products));

//This is not working
Mage::log(Mage::registry("orderproducts_products['product1']"));
```

How do i retrieve an array value from a registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling

```
Mage::log(Mage::registry("orderproducts_products['product1']"));
```

Magento looks in the registry for a key called `orderproducts_products['product1']` that doesn't exist. It something like:

```
Mage::$_registry["orderproducts_products['product1']"]
```

I think that what you need is:

```
$products = Mage::registry('orderproducts_products');
if (isset($products['product1'])){
    $product = $products['product1'];
}
else{
    $product = false;
}
//do something with $product
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an undefined index to retrieve the array. Try:

```
$registeredProducts = Mage::registry('orderproducts_products');
var_dump($registeredProducts);
```

FWIW what you are doing though seems a bit extraneous. I like the idea of not tying request global in all over the app, but your doing very much the same thing by using the registry.

Comment: array values are shown when i dump it

Comment: Right... That's what you want, to retrieve your array values from the registry, isn't it?